# Invalid Signature with Itext 7.2.2

Tags: java, digital-signature, itext7

I am signing a pdf document with itext in version 7.2.2, however the first one is invalidated when entering a second signature, could you help me tell me what I may be doing wrong?

```java
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader(pdfStream), byteNewPdf, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()); 
IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
IExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
signer.signDetached(digest, signature, chain, null, null,  null, signBoxData.getCmsSize(), subfilter);
```

I see that in the Producer label with the first signature the modified legend is added, I don't know if this may be affecting it?

Comment: Requires better formatting

Comment: From your description I thought you forgot to use append mode, but in your code you set it. Thus, it is unclear why the second signature invalidates the first one. For further analysis, therefore, please also share an example PDF illustrating the issue, both before and after the second signature. (It might indeed be a problem related to the PDF; some PDFs are broken in ways that usually causes no issue but makes Acrobat fail validation of signatures under certain circumstances.)

Comment: Hello mkl, I'm reviewing the example you shared about tryInitTagStructure however I still have the issue of invalidating the first signature, I'm using itext 7.2.2, bouncycastle 1.7.0.

Comment: Then the issue is caused by something else. And the document would be needed to analyze that.

Comment: Hello, I'm working with Itext 7.2.2, I'm trying to add a border to the signature box, well I add it with a canvas but when executing a second signature the first one is invalidated, any idea how I could solve this, with Itext 5 already I used to but so far I haven't been able to?

Answer (score 0):

[By having only one signature the document is valid, the same does not happen when another signature is inserted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4syLj.png)

[The image shows how the first signature was invalidated by the second, however when only one signature is inserted this does not happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJWTh.png)

I read that Itext 7 when adding a signature to the document also adds information to the document structure tree and that this may be causing the problem, however the solution they propose there has not worked for me.

Sorry I couldn't add the document

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).